# Can you ever decrement the build version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Ok so a small mistake was made when submitting an application.  The build number submitted was waaaaaaay to high.  lets say as an example:

Version 1.0.0
Build Number: 1000000004

I have tried to delete that uploaded build by itunes connect won't let me, which really sucks!

Can I ever decrement that build number?  I know that if I want to submit another version 1.0.0 build that I must increment, but what if I bump the version, can I start the build number over again?

Version 1.1
Build Number: 1

Any other way I might be able to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put a different and smaller Build Number in the next version with no problems.

> The Version Number and the Build Number values work together to
>   uniquely identify the build and release for a particular App Store
>   submission. For each new version of your App, you will provide a new
>   unique Version Number and you may provide one or more builds (or
>   submissions) each with a different and unique Build Number together
>   with that same Version Number. All Version Numbers used in an App must
>   be unique. You cannot re-use version numbers. Also, as you create new
>   releases, new Version Numbers must be added in ascending sequential
>   order.
>
> Build Numbers provide a way to name each of the submissions you
>   provide for a particular release. As described in the definitions
>   above, the collection of all of the builds that you provide for a
>   particular version of your App is called that version's 'release
>   train'. Build Numbers must be unique within each release train, but
>   they do not need to be unique across different release trains. That is
>   to say, you can use the same Build Numbers again in different release
>   trains if you want to. And, as you create and submit new builds for a
>   release, the Build Numbers you assign to them must be in ascending
>   sequential order.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2420/_index.html

Comment: Nope, build number must be higher, at least for the same version.  I am not sure if it can be lower if I change the version, hence the question.

Comment: In a different version he can change to a small number, 100% sure.

Comment: The Version Number and the Build Number values work together to uniquely identify the build and release for a particular App Store submission. For each new version of your App, you will provide a new unique Version Number and you may provide one or more builds (or submissions) each with a different and unique Build Number together with that same Version Number. All Version Numbers used in an App must be unique. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2420/_index.html

Comment: Cool, so if this is true then I will just have a crappy build number for this first release.  The next release I can change that to something more meaningful.